# Disambiguate the [arc] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request, tag-wiki

Let's face it. Nobody reads tag-wikis these days.

For this reason, the 5 most recent questions tagged as [arc](/questions/tagged/arc) are all [automatic-ref-counting](/questions/tagged/automatic-ref-counting) questions, which new users didn't read the tag wikis (or didn't care, frankly), and it just adds work for the moderators.

What if we disambiguate the [arc](/questions/tagged/arc) tag into three separate things:

[geometric-arc](/questions/tagged/geometric-arc) (used for the geometric arc shape)
[automatic-ref-counting](/questions/tagged/automatic-ref-counting) (used  for apple's automatic reference counting system) (done)
[php-arc](/questions/tagged/php-arc) (used for [Semantic Web Standards](http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/wiki/ARC) related questions)

Comment: If I could get some help fixing up the existing tags, I'll synonymize [arc] with [geometric-arc].

Comment: @Robert I think that I got most of them, but a few may have slipped through the cracks.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Things looked cleaned up here. Do we still want to do the [geometric-arc] synonym for [arc]?

Comment: @BradLarson I think so. It really will help new people coming in, to prevent mistagging. It's either that or blacklist the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've synonymized [arc](/questions/tagged/arc) and [automatic-ref-counting](/questions/tagged/automatic-ref-counting). Should make the correct tag a lot more obvious for the majority of folks asking questions, and at least doesn't make the situation any *worse* than blacklisting would for folks asking about geometry.

Answer (score 2):

I've retagged a few more questions, [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960123/cache-replacement-policies-implementation-of-arc) about adaptive cache replacement and a few about the [Arc programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_%28programming_language%29) for which there is the [arc-lisp](/questions/tagged/arc-lisp) tag.

I think [arc](/questions/tagged/arc) can safely be synonimized into [geometric-arc](/questions/tagged/geometric-arc) now.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the current state of [arc](/questions/tagged/arc) it seems that all the recent questions are for [automatic-ref-counting](/questions/tagged/automatic-ref-counting).

Should we do the cleanup again and then a mod move the rest to [geometric-arc](/questions/tagged/geometric-arc) as synomize won't work here,

Comment: I cleaned up a few. And I think a few other user also edited and retagged irrelevant questions. All noise should be gone by now.

Comment: I make a sweep of this tag once every couple of weeks. People are starting to get the idea, as far fewer questions are just tagged with [arc] compared to what we once saw.

Comment: Still the last 10 questions are all ref counting and 8 in the last two days

Comment: Now cleaned up can a mod please remove the tag now

Comment: @Mark Merged into [geometric-arc] and synonymized.

Comment: @AnnaLear - the point was not to synonymize but to remove arc now users will keep using arc probably for the wrong reason

Comment: @AnnaLear we are getting one arc question a day and all are automatic ref counting - can we delete the arc tag not synomize it

Comment: @Mark I removed the synonym. Sorry about that. I'll see about blacklisting it since it keeps getting misused.